# File referencing in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a React app, and I'm having some issues with referencing. My project structure is as follows:

- component
  -component_name.jsx(same name as parent folder)
  -component_styling.scss(also same name as parent folder)

In importing the component, I have to point to the folder then the component.
i.e. `import TestComponent from "../../TestComponent/TestComponent.jsx"`
The last part is really bugging me. Is there a way to just reference the folder but import the component in the folder since they have the same name.

**A friend recommended using a `jsconfig.json` file but I don't  know how to implement this.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the component folder, create a `index.js` file with the content like this:

```
export { default } from './TestComponent.jsx'
```

or

```
import TestComponent from './TestComponent.jsx';

export default TestComponent;
```

This way will solve your problem and when your folder growing up and you need to export another file like `util.js` or what ever to another folder using, let import to this `index.js` file and re-export it. I call this approach is `modularize` :D